# how to use a progress bar in electron

Tags: node.js, electron

So, I am building an electron application and that application compares two csv files and create a file with data which is in both files. Now while this process is running I want to show a progress bar on browser window so how can I create a progress bar that will show progress of that script ?
P.S:- I don't want to open any new browser window. everything should be on same window.

Comment: Please show us what you have tried.

Comment: I have called a function and passed value of progress. this function is called many times in between the script and every time a different value is passed. I know this is not the right way.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a simple progress bar by using nested divs:

```js
const progressBar = document.getElementById('bar');

function setBar(percentage) {
  progressBar.style.width = percentage + "%";
}
```

```css
#bar-container {
  width: 400px;
  height: 25px;
  background-color: lightgray;
}

#bar {
  width: 0;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: firebrick;
  transition: width 0.2s;
}
```

```html
<button onClick="setBar(0);">0%</button>
<button onClick="setBar(20);">20%</button>
<button onClick="setBar(40);">40%</button>
<button onClick="setBar(60);">60%</button>
<button onClick="setBar(80);">80%</button>
<button onClick="setBar(100);">100%</button>
<div id="bar-container">
  <div id="bar"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: progress bar is ready but i want to make it dynamic according to process running in another thread

Comment: Okay so your question is more about how to communicate the progress between the render and the main process?

Comment: yes you are right, there are two threads in renderer process one is ui and another is that script running. i want to create a dynamic progress bar that shows progress of that script running

Answer (score 0):

In your `index.html` (or which page want to use it) add a link, progress and script elements:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Demo progress</title>
</head>

<body>
    <a href="https://file-examples-com.github.io/uploads/2017/11/file_example_MP3_5MG.mp3" download >Download demo file</a>

    <progress value="0" max="100" id="progress"></progress>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        window.progress = document.getElementById('progress')
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

(If you want you can use this site for testing: https://file-examples.com/)

In your `main.js` file add this inside the `createWindow` function:

```
ses.on("will-download", (event, downloadItem, webContents) => {
    let fileName = downloadItem.getFilename();
    let fileSize = downloadItem.getTotalBytes();

    // This will save the file to your desktop: 
    downloadItem.setSavePath(app.getPath("desktop") + `/${fileName}`);

    downloadItem.on("updated", (event, state) => {
        let received = downloadItem.getReceivedBytes();

        if (state === 'progressing' && received) {
            let progress = Math.round((received / fileSize) * 100);
            webContents.executeJavaScript(`window.progress.value = ${progress}`)
        }
    });
});
```

When you click the link the progress bar will show your download status in your `index.html`.